# Post con Ajax en Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax, eloquent

Tengo un problema peculiar, en el proyecto que estoy trabajando deseo guardar los datos de un formulario enviados mediante ajax, el problema es que cuando hago el metodo POST los datos no se guardan en la base de datos, más sin embargo si paso solo el request los datos están llegando limpiamente

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public function store(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){

            $Radicado = Radicado::create([
                'consecutive'=> $request['consecutive'],
                'atention'=> $request['atention_radic'],
                'origin_id'=> $request['origin_radic'],
                'sede_id'=> auth()->user()->sede['id'],
                'program_id'=> $request['program_radic'],
                'first_name'=> $request['firstName'],
                'last_name'=> $request['lastName'],
                'origin_correo'=> $request['email'],
                'origin_cel'=> $request['celphon'],
                'type_reason'=> $request['type_reason_radic'],
                'reason_id'=> $request['reason_radic'],
                'affair'=> $request['affair'],
                'notes'=> $request['note']
            ]);

            return response()->json(true);
        }
    }
```

**MODELO**
[image: Aqui esta el modelo]

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
event.preventDefault();
    data_for = $form_create_radic.form('get values');

    $.ajaxSetup({headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }});
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/radicado",
      data: data_for,
      serializeForm: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(){
        spinner_load = '<i class="spinner loading icon" style="font-size: 7em !important"></i> Creando...';
        $('.icon.header').empty();
        $('.icon.header').append(spinner_load);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.alert({
          theme: 'Modern',
          icon: 'lh check circle outline icon',
          title: 'Está Hecho',
          content: 'Radicado creado con exito',
          type: 'blue',
          typeAnimated: true,
        })
      }
```

No entiendo cual es el problema de mi codigo si aparentemente todoe sta bien

Muchas gracias de ante mano

Comment: Desconozco `laravel`, pero creo que deberías usar `$request->input('nombre_de_campo')` en lugar de `$request['nombre_de_campo']`

Comment: Cómo es el request que llega? Puedes hacer un dump y mostrarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Estaba todo bien pero me estaba saltando una parte importante que era usar el modelo con
 `use App\Models\Radicado`

y como no podia ver el cual era el error por por ser ajax con metodo post, de todos modos gracias por sus respuestas chicos

Comment: Como información, para la proxima vez, tienes los logs de Laravel en `/storage/logs/laravel.log` donde se van registrando los errores.